# Adding code to every character within a string

Tags: php, string, addition

I need to create a 'word search' puzzle, where if you hover over a word, it changes colour, so that you can find it with ease.
For that, I have split the searching part and the words in `separate arrays`.
I want to add `x` to every character, with `'x'` being a random character.

I have no knowledge of what codes can help me achieve this.

A part of the puzzle:

-e-------------a--e-

-k--galabal---a---l-

-e-----------t----t-

-n-straatlantaarn-o-

-diuleg-----------u-

----kade----------w-

computer------------

(Without the breaklines)

With
Computer, galabal, straatlantaarn, geluid, kade
and some others as the words that need to be searched.
The puzzle is 20 x 20 characters.

Comment: give some example what you want.

Comment: can u add the example for both variables $letter and $ruweWoordzoeker

Comment: It's not clear to me how the string replace is supposed to change your puzzles colour, could you give more detailed examples of your words, search space, and code that displays stuff.

Comment: Can you show your entire code here that you had tried?

Comment: Sure, at first with the puzzle, you need to add certain words, which you document beneath the puzzle. Anything that isn't a word right now, is an '-' character. $letter > a random letter, from a to z. $ruweWoorzoeker > the file that needs '-' to be replaced with $letter.

Comment: Substantially, do you want that «-e-------------a--e-» will be output as «x**e**aflzgfhdspfdg**a**qd**e**w»?

Comment: Yes,I want the characters that aren't '-' to remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$letters = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");
for($x = 0; $x < count($ruweWoordzoeker); $x++ {
for($y = 0; $y < count($ruweWoordzoeker[$x]); $y++)
{
    if ($ruweWoordzoeker[$x][$y] == '-')
    {
        $ruweWoordzoeker[$x][$y] = $letters[array_rand($letters)];
    }
}
```

This was the solution to changing every '-' to a random letter.
The input is: `$ruweWoordzoeker` 
The output is: `$ruweWoordzoeker`

Answer (score 0):

I will try to point you in the right direction, without spoon-feeding the code.

Heres the algorithm.

1. Use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with the `whitespace` character as the `delimiter` to split all the words of the string to an array.
2. Loop through all the array elements and start creating the `HTML` output.
3. For each word, prepend it with a `<span class="word-highlight">`.
4. And append each word with a `</span>`
5. Remember to also append the whitespace back while re-creating the sentence.
6. Also keep the logic that handles the full stops and pronouns etc handy.
7. Now write the `CSS` code to handle the `:hover` event of mouse on the respective class (`.word-highlight` *in our case*), and subsequently change color.

Comment: I think OP wants to also change each '-' for a random character. Not just make the page look pretty.

Comment: That is my main intention, I want to make sure that '-' changes for a random letter. The rest of the code I want to do myself, so I can learn instead of copy. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.